# Can I deploy JSP websites through Docker?

Tags: jsp, docker

I've been recently studying Docker and I have learned a fair amount of stuff about pulling images, developing, deploying, etc.

My question is can I deploy my JSP + mysql website through Docker?
I only see tutorials like deploying Spring Boot war through Docker. Is it possible to deploy JSP through Docker?

Thank you!

Comment: Much too broad question, but why not? Did you try?

Comment: @Henry, my question is can you deploy a war file that is not an executable Spring Boot. Like plain JSP with some mysql databases, but no frameworks.

Comment: Sure, use a base image with tomcat in it. I would take a second container for the DB.

Comment: @Henry, do you mind if you post a simple answer showing deploying a very simple jsp website through Docker? Because I really don't know how to do it. Is this too much for you? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: May this help y si no pos tal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198073/spring-boot-application-giving-page-not-found-error-for-jsp-with-docker-containe